# Dask:read_sql_table gives KeyError + Dask join with composite index usability

Tags: pandas, sqlalchemy, dask, dask-dataframe

I'm trying to read a simple table and ending up with key error not sure what the deal here

please see my code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa
import dask.dataframe as ddf

start_time = datetime.now() 

sqluri = f'oracle+cx_oracle://test:test@PROD1:1522/?service_name=prddb'
engine = sa.create_engine(sqluri)

daskDF = ddf.read_sql_table(table='test1', uri=sqluri, index_col='ID',schema='testusr')
```

Also, can we use the SQL join in the following manner

```
sa_meta = sa.MetaData()
sa_table = sa.Table("test1", sa_meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
sa_query= sa.select("select /*+ PARALLEL(8) */ a.* , a.id||a.period as d_idx from test1 a join test2 b on test1.id=test2.id where a.acct='Client'")
ddf = dd.read_sql_table(sa_query, sqluri, index_col="d_idx ")
```

Comment: @mdurant any suggestion sir?

Comment: Sorry, what is your issue? Perhaps include a traceback.

Comment: Note that your sqlalchemy attempt is using the ORM rather than the pure expression system. Only the latter works.

Comment: @mdurant so for the latter part . I have the underlying table with a composite PK, hence was trying to concatenate them in the query as above, which results error as "ArgumentError: Textual column expression 's' should be explicitly declared with text('s'), or use column('s') for more specificity"... Does the underlying table needs a unique index or can it be a non unique index? can u suggest a syntax on how to use the above parallel SQL query

Comment: See [this line](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/master/dask/dataframe/io/tests/test_sql.py#L320) from the tests for an example of the syntax

Comment: @mdurant tried index = sql.func.abs(sql.column("Id"))||sql.func.abs(sql.column("period")).label("c_idx") and i get error?

Comment: Now you can update your question with what you tried and show your error in full.